# Is the Spring application multithreaded or not?

Tags: java, spring

I need to create several services in which endless cycles will be spinning, with the possibility of stopping them.
It seems like it begs to implement everything in separate threads.
I tried to create them in a Spring application by writing a small test application.
The use of Spring in this application is due to the fact that you will have to connect a web interface to it. The built-in Apache Tomcat web server is used.

```
@Service
public class FirstService
 public isStart = false;
 private action() {
    while (isStart) {
        ... 
    } 
 }
}
@Service
public class NextService
 public isStart = false;
 private action() {
    while (isStart) {
        ... 
    } 
 }
}
```

The service is started and stopped via controllers

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  FirstService firstService;
  
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> post(@PathVariable(PARAM_ACTION) Integer action) {
    firstService.isStart = ...;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It seems like everything works, i.e. it turns out that the application is multithreaded? Otherwise, everything would stop until the first action method is executed
Question:
Should I create a multithreaded application if everything is already working? Or is this not a very good solution and still need to be implemented using a standard solution with threads?
Or maybe Spring has another ready-made solution for such cases as well?

I would like to use something ready-made from Spring to solve this problem. But I do not know which of its components can help me with this. The main requirement is speed, the cycle time should not exceed 20 ms, i.e. it should not be very heavy components. In each iteration of the cycle, 300 to 800 bytes of data are received by the EHT, processed and sent to another address. And there can be from three to five such services at the same time. If Spring has components that will cope with such a task, then I will be glad if you tell me their names, and I will already study them.
In other words, I need advice on which direction to dig, use some component from Spring, or start studying multithreaded applications and create my own component.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you’re using spring-web or spring-webflux, the default web server is Tomcat or Netty, respectively. Both are multithreaded. In fact, I don’t know of any web server in the market that isn’t. If you want to fine tune the thread pool, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your service classes are usual class and not synchronized. any class in spring has a scope and by default they are singleton. In web spring just one thread is responsible for executing all your request but in webflux because of none blocking nature every idle thread is used to proceed the request. but if you want to write concurrent app you must use multi-threading mechanism like synchronize or locking solutions

Comment: Then why does everything work? I get a REST request to start an infinite loop. I launch it, it starts working. I get another REST request to stop it. And it works, the service stops. If it was a single thread, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: by your second service call you are sending signal to stop the thread. if i have understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's right